# Does any design change in the flag have to be amended by an executive order from the President?

Tags: united-states

> On January 3rd, 1959 Alaska was formally granted statehood placing the
> 49th star on our Flag. Executive Order of President Eisenhower dated
> January 3, 1959 - provided for the arrangement of the stars in seven
> rows of seven stars each, staggered horizontally and vertically.

https://www.chamberofcommerce.org/usflag/the.49.star.flag.html

Here, it says it was an executive order of the president that brougth the change, but I am wondering if Congress as such power to bring about a design change in the flag of the United States.

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31320/can-the-president-unilaterally-change-the-design-of-the-us-flag?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the President unilaterally change the design of the US flag?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31320/can-the-president-unilaterally-change-the-design-of-the-us-flag)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No, it does not have to be an executive order. Yes, it can be an Act of Congress

From the same [site](https://www.chamberofcommerce.org/usflag/the.15.star.flag.html) you cite:

> The 15-star, 15-stripe flag was authorized by the Flag Act of January 13, 1794, adding 2 stripes and 2 Stars.

Answer (score 15):

Certain elements of the flag's design are specified by statute, namely [4 USC 1-2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/4/chapter-1):

> §1 The flag of the United States shall be thirteen horizontal stripes, alternate red and white; and the union of the flag shall be forty-eight stars, white in a blue field.
>
> §2 On the admission of a new State into the Union one star shall be added to the union of the flag; and such addition shall take effect on the fourth day of July then next succeeding such admission.

The rest of the design is specified by executive order ([EO 10834](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/codification/executive-order/10834.html), to be precise).  I won't quote the whole thing here, because it's rather heavy on detail, but it includes a couple of tables and a detailed diagram specifying the dimensions of the flag and the arrangement of the stars.

The president can change anything that has been specified by executive order, and can specify additional details that haven't been specified, as long as nothing in the president's order contradicts the statute.  Congress can add additional details to the statutory specifications, in which case the president's orders might have to be modified to comply.

Comment: Was §2 in effect in 1959 (or when did come into effect)? That would mean the 49 star flag came into effect on the 4th of July 1959 and the 50 star flag on 4th of July 1960.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, 1818 Flag Act. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_Acts#Flag_Act_of_1818